# Real time use of abstract, sealed and static class

Tags: c#, .net, static, abstract, sealed

If I've some common functionality that I've to keep in a class, so will I go for static, sealed or abstract class...Does all these types of classes serve the purpose of keeping the common functionality together...where actually the difference lies when I've to go for one

Comment: Can anyone please help what are the scenarios where we have to choose one among the abstract, sealed and static class

Comment: You should start here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21028.difference-between-static-class-sealed-class-and-abstract-class-in-c.aspx

Comment: Your question appears too broad. Maybe you can rephrase it to be more concrete? What scenario are you trying to implement?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen..but as I said these articles only tells you the what are these and the theoretical differences...none of these actually tell in which situations we have to go for these...When I have to make a class sealed not abstract....what change it brings if I go for abstract not sealed or vice versa....Hope you understand my case

Comment: The vote down (not me) is not, because you question is bad, it's because it out of scope for stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is about being stuck (on a bug) within your software. Posting a question and some example code  (like what you have tried) and some explination where you are stuck on. Guys like us tries to understand the problem and giving hints/solutions to get you back on the track.

Answer (score 2):

abstract, sealed, static has nothing to do with real time development. It has to do with bring structure within your software, so that the functionality implemented in classes can and should be used in the right way.

---

*After some comments i think this:*

I think you can only learn this, by doing it. There isn't a book or epub that will explain you how to do programming. They will show the syntax and some examples. It will be trial and error. Every day you'll face a new challenge.
You'll have to practice it. The best advise is, look what others already created and try to imagine why did they wrote/solve it that way.

I can explain what a static/sealed/abstract class is/does, but it doesn't learn you when to use it.

---

Back to the question: Define 'real time'..  I think that static/abstract/sealed should NOT be decisive on how you write your 'real-time' software. If you are 'scared' about performance on this level, C# should not be your choise. I would write c++ or if you want a real challenge, try to beat the compilers with asm ;-)

I think you won't measure the 'overhead'

So, use abstract/static/sealed in a right way, so your future collega's/you can read/maintain it.

I use C# for communication (tcp/ip) between a windows computer and a PLC (with delta robots). But it's far from realtime. It's fast enough to keep many robot working with > 100 messages per second.

Comment: Just a little more help I would seek from you...If I take Console class and TextWriter class....why is one static and another abstract

Comment: I think what @BhuwanPandey is looking for is the actually implementation of these features in development. As opposed to the differences listed in text or in academia.

Comment: @MattRowland Thank You...at least I've one who could understand my case and situation

Comment: @BhuwanPandey try editing the original question to be a little more descriptive.

Comment: @MattRowland I did a whole lot of search on Gooogle....but I end up those difference between lines....could not get when we have to go for these

Comment: @BhuwanPandey I mean edit the original question to clarify your need a little more. This way others and Jeroen can help you out a little more.

Comment: From what I know there are some negligible differences between virtual vs. non-virtual calls. However, members on abstract cannot be called (only implemented members in derived classes that implement the abstract members) so the original question does not make any sense at least with regards to abstract classes.